Extracting Video and file info from PDF using PyMuPDF
I am using PyMuPDF to extract PDF data - words, text, dimensions, coors, etc - and am trying to use Annot to also extract embedded videos. I'm using documentation from https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/annot.html#Annot.get_file and referenced the answer given How to extract images, video and audio from a pdf file using python The below code returns the following output:
page = doc[68]
annot = page.first_annot


'RichMedia' annotation on page 68 of pdf filename here

So that part seems to be working
But in using the solution provided in the above linked answer, where
cont = doc.xref_get_key(annot.xref, "RichMediaContent/Assets/Names")
array = cont[1][1:-1] 
xref = array[i + 1 :]
xref = int(xref[:-4])

the line
xref = int(xref[:-4])  returns the following error:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '12855 0 R12856 0 R<FEFF0056006900640065006F0050006C0061007900650072002E00

And trying annot.get_file() returns

TypeError: bad annot type

I assume that I should be able to extract the filename and extract the coordinates of the embedded video. Any insight?
